# train_test_split raises value error regarding the train set

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, training-data, train-test-split

```
X = features(game_pokemon_df)
print("X", X)
Y = targets(game_pokemon_df)
print("Y", Y)
feature = X.reshape(-1, len(X))
target = Y.reshape(-1, len(Y))
print("feature", feature)

xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(feature, target, test_size = 0.25, train_size = 0.75, random_state = 42)
```

The training model has worked in the past with similar datavalues and the same parameters. I have tried leaving the train size as None and switching the positions of the train_size and test_size but that changed nothing.

```
ValueError: With n_samples=1, test_size=0.25 and train_size=0.75, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.
```

The ValueError is raised where the trainset is empty, even though the data values entered into the training model are accurate and the same exact model has worked with similar data in the past.

```
feature = X.reshape(-1, len(X))
target = Y.reshape(-1, len(Y))
```

```
def features(data_df):
    text_char_num = len(data_df["text"])
    array_y_value = data_df["authorkarma"]
    global feature
    feature = np.array([text_char_num, array_y_value], dtype = object)
    return feature
features(game_pokemon_df)
```

```
def targets(data_df):
    global target
    target = np.array(data_df["ups"], dtype=object)
    return target
def ups_val(data_df):
    global up_val
    up_val = max(targets(data_df))
    print("Max value of the target is: ", up_val)
    return up_val
targets(game_pokemon_df)
ups_val(game_pokemon_df)
```

```
Name: authorkarma, Length: 4317, dtype: int64]
Name: authorkarma, Length: 4317, dtype: int64]]
```

I assumed that the problem must lie with the numpy arrays and the sizes, but the sizes are the same and based on my research that isn't the problem in this case.
Thank You!

Comment: Somewhere in your weird global based reprocessing of your dataset you have ended up with one row. It's hard to know where the problem is as a result. You should refactor everything imo. This code is not usable.

Comment: @CJR thank you for letting me know. I am pretty new to programming so do you have any idea on what I should change or are you saying I should start from scratch?

Comment: Forget the global keyword and never use it again for any reason. I would print debug the sizes of everything before you call train test split, and also use .transpose() if you're trying to transpose a matrix. The reshape you're doing is not the same thing.

Comment: @CJR I fixed the global variables and messed around with np.transpose() and the traintestsplit is working as it is meant to now. Thank You!